# Java | How to parse this ('3-level') xml using JAXB?

Tags: java, jaxb

I want to learn JAXB and I have a problem with my sample xml file.
xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
<books>
    <book id="bk101">
        <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
        <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
        <genre>Computer</genre>
        <price>44.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
        <description>An in-depth look at creating applications
            with XML.</description>
    </book>
<book id="bk102">
    <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
    <title>Midnight Rain</title>
    <genre>Fantasy</genre>
    <price>5.95</price>
    <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
    <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies,
        an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen
        of the world.</description>
</book>
<book id="bk103">
    <author>Corets, Eva</author>
    <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
    <genre>Fantasy</genre>
    <price>5.95</price>
    <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
    <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology
        society in England, the young survivors lay the
        foundation for a new society.</description>
</book>
<book id="bk104">
    <author>Corets, Eva</author>
    <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
    <genre>Fantasy</genre>
    <price>5.95</price>
    <publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date>
    <description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious
        agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life
        for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve
        Ascendant.</description>
</book>
<book id="bk105">
    <author>Corets, Eva</author>
    <title>The Sundered Grail</title>
    <genre>Fantasy</genre>
    <price>5.95</price>
    <publish_date>2001-09-10</publish_date>
    <description>The two daughters of Maeve, half-sisters,
        battle one another for control of England. Sequel to
        Oberon's Legacy.</description>
</book>
<book id="bk106">
    <author>Randall, Cynthia</author>
    <title>Lover Birds</title>
    <genre>Romance</genre>
    <price>4.95</price>
    <publish_date>2000-09-02</publish_date>
    <description>When Carla meets Paul at an ornithology
        conference, tempers fly as feathers get ruffled.</description>
</book>
<book id="bk107">
    <author>Thurman, Paula</author>
    <title>Splish Splash</title>
    <genre>Romance</genre>
    <price>4.95</price>
    <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
    <description>A deep sea diver finds true love twenty
        thousand leagues beneath the sea.</description>
</book>
<book id="bk108">
    <author>Knorr, Stefan</author>
    <title>Creepy Crawlies</title>
    <genre>Horror</genre>
    <price>4.95</price>
    <publish_date>2000-12-06</publish_date>
    <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches,
        centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
</book>
<book id="bk109">
    <author>Kress, Peter</author>
    <title>Paradox Lost</title>
    <genre>Science Fiction</genre>
    <price>6.95</price>
    <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
    <description>After an inadvertant trip through a Heisenberg
        Uncertainty Device, James Salway discovers the problems
        of being quantum.</description>
</book>
<book id="bk110">
    <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
    <title>Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible</title>
    <genre>Computer</genre>
    <price>36.95</price>
    <publish_date>2000-12-09</publish_date>
    <description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in
        detail in this deep programmer's reference.</description>
</book>
<book id="bk111">
    <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
    <title>MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
    <genre>Computer</genre>
    <price>36.95</price>
    <publish_date>2000-12-01</publish_date>
    <description>The Microsoft MSXML3 parser is covered in
        detail, with attention to XML DOM interfaces, XSLT processing,
        SAX and more.</description>
</book>
<book id="bk112">
    <author>Galos, Mike</author>
    <title>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
    <genre>Computer</genre>
    <price>49.95</price>
    <publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date>
    <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
        looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are
        integrated into a comprehensive development
        environment.</description>
</book>
</books>
<movies>
    <movie id="m101">
        <author>George Lucas</author>
        <title>Star Wars</title>
        <genre>Science Fiction</genre>
        <price>32.95</price>
    </movie>
    <movie id="m202">
        <author>Francis Ford Coppola</author>
        <title>The Godfather</title>
        <genre>Drama</genre>
        <price>36.95</price>
    </movie>
</movies>
</catalog
```

There's my code, it doesn't work. 
Main:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Path: ");
    String filePath = scanner.next();

    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Catalog.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    Catalog catalog = (Catalog) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File(filePath));

    // test
    System.out.println("All titles in uploaded catalog: ");

    for (int b = 0; b<catalog.getBooks().getBookList().size(); b++) {
        catalog.getBooks().getBookList().get(b).getTitle();
        catalog.getBooks().getBookList().get(b).getPrice();
    }

    for (int m = 0; m<catalog.getMovies().getMovieList().size(); m++) {
        catalog.getMovies().getMovieList().get(m).getTitle();
        catalog.getMovies().getMovieList().get(m).getPrice();
    }

}
}
```

Book:

omitted for brevity
Movie:

omitted for brevity
Books:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "books")
public class Books {

private List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();

@XmlElements(@XmlElement(name = "books"))
public List<Book> getBookList() {
    return bookList;
}

public void setBookList(List<Book> bookList) {
    this.bookList = bookList;
}
}
```

Movies:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "movies")
public class Movies {

private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<>();

@XmlElements(@XmlElement(name = "movies"))
public List<Movie> getMovieList() {
    return movieList;
}

public void setMovieList(List<Movie> movieList) {
    this.movieList = movieList;
}
}
```

Catalog:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "catalog")
public class Catalog {
private Books books = new Books();

private Movies movies = new Movies();

//@XmlElements(@XmlElement(name = "books"))
public Books getBooks() {
    return books;
}

public void setBooks(Books books) {
    this.books = books;
}

//@XmlElements(@XmlElement(name = "movies"))
public Movies getMovies() {
    return movies;
}

public void setMovies(Movies movies) {
    this.movies = movies;
}
}
```

I think there could exist some errors in Catalog class, but I don't have ideas how to modify it, moreover I tried convert it to xsd and use xcj to generate classes, but I actually xcj is not working on my OS. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: I've omitted Movie and Book class, because Stack Overflow didn't let me post that much code with this amount of ordinary text

Comment: Describe "it doesn't work". What is the problem?

Comment: Fields of instance catalog are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually drop the intermediate `Books` or `Movies` classes, you don't need them. Here's a version using `@XmlElementWrapper`:

```
public class Catalog {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="books")
    @XmlElement(name="book")
    public List<Book> books;

}

public class Book {

    @XmlAttribute
    public String id;
    public String author;
    public String title;
    public String genre;
    public BigDecimal price;
    @XmlElement(name="publish_date")
    public XMLGregorianCalendar publishDate;
    public String description;
}
```

A test:

```
@Test
public void unmarshallsCatalog() throws JAXBException, IOException {

    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Catalog.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
    try (InputStream is = Thread.currentThread()
                              .getContextClassLoader()
                              .getResourceAsStream("catalog.xml")) {

        Catalog catalog = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(is), Catalog.class).getValue();
        Assert.assertEquals(catalog.books.size(), 12);

    }
}
```

The following also worked for me:

```
public class Catalog {
    public Books books; 
}

public class Books {
    @XmlElement(name = "book")
    public List<Book> bookList;
}
```

I think your error is probably in the `Books` class:

```
@XmlElements(@XmlElement(name = "books"))
public List<Book> getBookList() {
    return bookList;
}
```

You have to map `book` elements, not `books` elements.

Also an annotation like `@XmlElements(@XmlElement(name = "books"))` does not do what you probably think it does. It does not map a list of `books`. With one element it does not even make sense.

`@XmlElements` can be used to map different elements onto one property. Assume you'd have an XML like:

Gambardella, Matthew
        XML Developer's Guide
        Computer
        44.95
        2000-10-01
        An in-depth look at creating applications
            with XML.
    
    
        George Lucas
        Star Wars
        Science Fiction
        32.95

Basically, `book`s and `movie`s mixed in one catalog. `Book` and `Movie` could implement the same interface `Item`. In this case you may want to map both elements `book` and `movie` to the same property `items`. This is how you'd do it:

```
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name="book", type=Book.class),
    @XmlElement(name="movie", type=Movie.class)
})
public List<? extends Item> items;
```

Depending on the element name JAXB will unmarshal `Book`s or `Movie`s and add them to the `items` list.

Answer (score 0):

after getting unmarshalled your movies list and book list is getting null.because you have not annotated it correctly

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "books")
public class Books {

private List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();

public Books() {

}

@XmlElements(@XmlElement(name = "book")) ------ note the change here
public List<Book> getBookList() {
    return bookList;
}
```

after this Override toString() method in every Pojo class , So that you check if your class is getting values after unmarshalling .

for example:

```
 `@XmlRootElement(name = "catalog")  
   public class Catalog {
   private Books books = new Books();

private Movies movies = new Movies();

@XmlElements(@XmlElement(name = "books"))
public Books getBooks() {
    return books;
}

public void setBooks(Books books) {
    this.books = books;
}

@XmlElements(@XmlElement(name = "movies"))
public Movies getMovies() {
    return movies;
}

public void setMovies(Movies movies) {
    this.movies = movies;
}

@Override    -------> this will give you what values are extracted in your object
public String toString() {
    return "Catalog [books=" + books + ", movies=" + movies + "]";
}
```

}`

In the main class ...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Path: ");
    String filePath = scanner.next();

    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Catalog.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    Catalog catalog = (Catalog) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File(filePath));


    System.out.println("All titles in uploaded catalog: ");
    System.out.println(catalog); ----> here you will see what values are getting in the catalog object from xml

}
```

hope this helps..

Comment: `@XmlElements(@XmlElement(name = "books"))` does not really makes sense. If it's just one element, there is no need for `@XmlElements`.